# format phone no - using regex

Tags: php, regex

I need to create a function named **ReformatPhoneNumber()**.

calling **ReformatPhoneNumber(’012-345 69′)** the return value should be ’01234569′. Calling the function with any of these values: ’012345′, ‘-012345 678′, ’01203- 34566′, ’123456678875432′, ’1234×567′ **should result in an exception**.

for achieving the above, have done below:-

```
function ReformatPhoneNumber($number)
{
    if (preg_match('/^(\d[ -]?){7,12}$/', $number, $matches))
    {
        return preg_replace('/[ -]/', '', $number);
    }

    throw new Exception('Invalid phone number');
}
```

But when I'm calling with:

```
echo ReformatPhoneNumber('012-345   49');
```

Then this giving me below error:-

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Invalid phone number'**

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue: https://eval.in/95760 - what PHP/PCRE version do you have?

Comment: Why not strip all non-digits from the string then see if the phone number contains the proper amount of characters?

Answer (score 3):

Your Regex needs to be more finite:

```
\d{3}-\d{3} \d{2}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/183JLn8ewN2qFk_o)

Comment: @ripa, I'm glad I could be of assistance. Please consider accepting it as the answer.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: I agree the regex could be improved, but I'm just curious: are you able to reproduce the OP's issue? As in, do you get the same error when you try to run the OP's code (provided in the question) **as it is**? When I tried it, I got the following results: https://eval.in/95760

Comment: @AmalMurali, no I did not reproduce the OP's issue and I'll be honest, I can't argue with those results. Based on what you've got it **seems** to work.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: I tested this on 19 different PHP versions in this [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/), and I can't seem to reproduce this issue on any of the versions. Interesting. (+1 to you!)

Comment: @Michael Perrenoud , changing only the above new format , error message is not solving. At last, I found the answer. Please check my answer. I'm posting it.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the below for solution of my question:-

```
function ReformatPhoneNumber($number)
{
    if (!preg_match('/^(\d[ -]?){7,12}$/', $number, $matches))
    {
        throw new Exception('Invalid phone number');

    }

    return preg_replace('/[ -]/', '', $number);
}



try {
    echo ReformatPhoneNumber('01203- 34566');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Now it's giving proper output mentioned in my question.

check it from [eval.in/95920](https://eval.in/95920)

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes because you have more than one space in your string.

Have a try with:

```
function ReformatPhoneNumber($number) {
    if (preg_match('/^(\d[ -]*){7,12}$/', $number, $matches))
    //     note the change __^
        return preg_replace('/[ -]/', '', $number);

    throw new Exception('Invalid phone number');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. But check my previous comment and my answer.